# Tridion Upgrade to 2011 has few Deprecated Classes

Tags: 2011

We are upgrading Tridion 2009 to 2011 version and could see that there are few Classes deprecated like com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.Page com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.Binary
com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.BinaryKey

we are using these classes in our CustomDeployer. So do we have any alternative for this . Can any one guide us on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Java Docs from `Tridion World`, this document will tell you if you class is deprecated and which class is replacing it.

In the case of the Transport Package classes, they are internal classes so not sure if the java docs will tell you which ones are replacing them. good luck.

Comment: Yeah , I have already Checked java docs, It say'that "TransportPackage is internal API, please do not use." But in my deployerextension pagekey object is returning page object where this is deprecated. So any solutions for this?